# Class function is undefined inside subscribe in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I have a class like below which has a function called test.

```
export class Vehicle{

    plate:String;
    test(){
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

I am returning vehicle data from the server and access to the Test function, however i am getting an error saying "Function test is undefined".

```
this.vehicleService.get(this.vehicleId).subscribe((vehicle:Vehicle)=>{
                    vehicle.test(); //test function here is undefined.
                });
```

I understand data is somehow converted into an object with type Vehicle. But i am loosing access to its properties (in this case test function).
Is there any way to access to test function in this scenario ?

Comment: in your vehicle service how did you convert the json data to Vehicle object?

Comment: You should define the API call return types as `interface` not `class`.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue , you can mark it as "Answer" so other devs with same issue will know if it is solved, also you got some scores as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't convert `json` vehicle data coming from your backend to a `Vehicle` object

```
export class Vehicle{

    plate:String;
    constructor(params: Vehicle) { 
       Object.assign(this, params);
    }

    test(){
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

now you can create an instance of `Vehicle` by this code

```
const instance = new Vehicle({plate:'xxx'})
```

and you can do the same in your service by using `.map(item => return new Vehicle(item))`

Answer (score 0):

Make public the function

```
export class Vehicle{

   plate:String;
   public test(){
     console.log("test");
   }
}
```

Import the class in your file where you want to use it:

```
import { Vehicle } from 'path_to_Vehicle.ts'
```

Declare a variable for the class Vehicle;

```
VehicleClass: Vehicle = new Vehicle();
```

Now you can access to the method test() of Vehicle Class implementing as follow:

```
this.vehicleService.get(this.vehicleId).subscribe((vehicle:Vehicle)=>{
   this.VehicleClass.test();
});
```

Comment: in TS by default methods are public, if vehicleService doesn't create an instance of Vehicle your code doesn't work

Comment: Hello daniel thanks for the reply. However this does not answer my question, i need to be able to do vehicle.test().